# read all table header column names in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, typescript2.0

below is my table structure. i want to read all table  tags or header columns in typescript.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>dob</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

actual my intension is to read all table headers ( tags) and wanted to apply css class like below here i don't want to hard code

```
document.getElementById("name").className = "defaultSort"; 
document.getElementById("dob").className = "defaultSort";
```

Please anyone can help here

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

```
document.querySelectorAll("#uniqueTableName th")
```

This will get all table header elements, loop over it to set different classes etc to it.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, there are two tables in same page so we will get all <th> tags.

Comment: Can you give a class or an id to your tables. This way you can select ".classname th" or "#id th"